# Can't communicate locally on eth0 and to internet on wlan0

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

Looked at other configuration Q&A about eth0 and wlan0. Nothing suggested seemed to work. Running 14.04 Lubuntu on desktop, and puppyLinux on client laptop.

```
frank@HP-Pavilion:~$ ifconfig

"eth0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr: 00:18:f3:31:19:d6
         UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500  METRIC:1
         RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
         RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5687 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5687 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:531647 (531.6 KB)  TX bytes:531647 (531.6 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:91:f5:53:47:23  
          inet addr:192.168.1.66  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2602:306:31b6:dbd0:e291:f5ff:fe53:4723/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2602:306:31b6:dbd0:389a:6c14:8305:81ca/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::e291:f5ff:fe53:4723/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:23561 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:20483 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10010457 (10.0 MB)  TX bytes:3313915 (3.3 MB)
"
```

Notice that there is not an IP address for eth0 even though the interface has a hardware address.

Setup on the client PC, puppypc:

```
Puppy_Network_Setup

Enter you static IP parameters:
- If you are using a router check your router’s
status page to get these values.
- If you connect directly to your modem you will
need to get these values from your ISP.

Please enter all addresses in dotted-quad decimal
format (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx). other formats will
not be recognized.


Static IP parameters
IP address: 192.168.1.72
Net Mask:   255.255.255.0
Gateway:    192.168.1.254

DNS parameters

Primary:    192.168.1.254
Secondary:  8.8.8.8
```

The ethernet interface on the node puppypc is unable to connect to the Internet. If I add a static IP address of 192.168.1.70 to eth0 on my desktop, HP-Pavilion, I get messages of “unable to resolve host: HP-Pavilion”. There appears to be a conflict between wlan0 and eth0.

What should the configuration of eth0 and wlan0 be for Lubuntu 14.04.3 to allow communication locally between computers, and wireless connection to the internet?

Changed client pc to HPMini running Lubuntu 14.04.3. Connected ethernet cable to desktop. Client pc booted with ethernet showing instead of its wireless interface. Desktop ifconfig eth0 showed inet: 10.42.0.1, Bcast: 10.42.0.255. The HPMini ifconfig eth0 showed inet: 10.42.0.57, Bcast: 10.42.0.255. DNS Servers 127.0.1.1, and Search Domain attlocal.net.

The question can be withdrawn.

Comment: PuppyLinux is off-topic here.  What's the problem with the Ubuntu machine? (unclear to me)